# JavaFX Webview on a Swing application not loading content which loads properly on standard web browsers

Tags: java, swing, javafx, webview, orthanc-server

I have a Java/Swing application through which I want to load and display web pages from this URL : http://funsoft.systempartners.biz:8042/stone-webviewer/index.html?study=2.16.840.1.113669.632.20.1211.1000035777

This URL has testing content only. The JavaFX Webview component tries to load it indefinitely while it loads instantly on standard web browsers.

Many versions of JavaFX have been tested but with similar results, the latest one being 16.

I have attached the code that I am using below. Any suggestions on why the content cannot be processed successfully? Much appreciation in advance.

Thanks,

Charles

My code:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Charles Waweru <cwaweru@systempartners,biz>
 */
public class PacsViewerMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("pACS Viewer");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 833, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
//        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            PacsViewerMain jFrameTest = new PacsViewerMain();
            jFrameTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrameTest.setExtendedState(javax.swing.JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            jFrameTest.add(jfxPanel);

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
//                jFrameTest.setMaximumSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
                jFrameTest.setVisible(true);
                WebView webView = new WebView();
                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
                // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
                };

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
                try {
                    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                }
                webView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getEngine().getCreatePopupHandler(); //setOnAlert(null);
                webView.getEngine().load("http://funsoft.systempartners.biz:8042/stone-webviewer/index.html?study=2.16.840.1.113669.632.20.1211.1000035777");
            });
//        });
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        Text text = new Text();

        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");

        root.getChildren().add(text);

        return (scene);
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Correction on URL

Comment: http://funsoft.systempartners.biz:8042/stone-webviewer/index.html?study=2.16.840.1.113669.632.20.1211.10000357775

Comment: Does it work in plain JavaFX (i.e. without embedding the `WebView` in Swing)?

Comment: @Slaw, I have not tried it that way. Our primary development environment is Swing so we were only looking for a browser and JavaFX/Webview came up.

Comment: Testing if it works in plain JavaFX would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Slaw, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it with a plain JavaFX application extending Application with similar results.

Comment: It appears that the Stone Web Viewer tool may require some functionality that is yet to be implemented on JavaFX Webview. I have tried the alternative viewer Osimis Web Viewer which is almost similar and that works well.